# From several variables to JSON stringified string

Tags: java

What is the best practice for creating a JSON object and then stringify it in Java?

This is how I do it in JavaScipt:

```
var1 = "foo";
var2 = "bar";

resultObj = { var1: var1, var2: var2 };
resultString = JSON.stringify(resultObj);
```

Being so junior in Java the only thing that comes to mind is to concatenate text in JSON format, but this other than being not very clean it can also give me problems with not scaped chars, like quotes. Are there any functions in the Java language to do this as simple as you can do it in JavaScript?

Comment: FYI, and to help your further research, this is process is often called *serializing* to JSON

Comment: Take a look at library that does whatever you needed it here in the question e.g. [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: There are quiet few JSON libraries that can help you out, JACKSON / ORg.JSON / Google GSON. they might help you out.